# Converting image to mpeg/mp4 results in mp4 file with 0 bytes

Tags: ffmpeg, image-conversion

I'm trying to convert a png file to mp4 file but I get 0bytes mp4 files.

Here is my code structure:

```
ffmpeg -r [framerate] -i [images] -s [resolution] -vcodec libx264 [videofilename].mp4
```

Comment: You need to show your actual command and the complete console output.

Answer (score 0):

When creating film from images, you need to specify input "framerate" as decribed in 
[Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Putting tag `-framerate 1/5` before tag `-i` for example will make each image be shown for 5s in the film.

Comment: I added it but I'm still getting the same issue, my ffmpeg version is FFmpeg 0.6.5

Comment: Current version is 3.x. You should upgrade.